# Como tratar customizações especificas com o git

Tags: git, versionamento

Onde eu trabalho, seguimos a seguinte metodologia ao trabalhar com o git

- Temos uma branch de produção
- Temos uma branch de homologação
- E criamos branchs para cada sprint de desenvolvimento

Mas surgiu a necessidade de criar customizações especificas para alguns clientes, qual seria a maneira mais correta de se versionar o mesmo? Criando uma branch para o cliente com as customizações dele?

Se for necessário, aceito sugestões para melhorar nosso fluxo de desenvolvimento atual

Comment: Todos usam a mesma base de código? Se sim, talvez estratégia de submódulos seria o melhor, não?

Comment: Acho que o recomendado seria algo como o GitFlow sugere https://medium.com/trainingcenter/utilizando-o-fluxo-git-flow-e63d5e0d5e04

Comment: @hugocsl pelo que eu entendi, eles meio que já usam git-flow, só que eles querem criar "subprojetos" em que descendem do projeto principal e é customizado para cada cliente

Comment: Exatamente @FelipeAvelar, essa é a ideia e respondendo sua pergunta, sim todos usam a mesma base, as alterações para cada clientes são pequenas, principalmente na forma com que as informações são exibidas

Answer (score 1):

Pelas informações que você passa na pergunta, o que vocês parecem precisar são [submódulos](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos) de um projeto pai.

No caso o projeto principal de vocês será um [superprojeto](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos#Superprojetos) terá vários submódulos sendo que cada customização de cliente será um submódulo, de forma que as alterções dessas customizações ficarão "isoladas" dentro de cada submódulo, sendo replicável por todo o repositório de vocês. Isso isolará as alterações, de forma que pra cada cliente, você poderá gerar um produto final diferente.

Para resumir, o conceito de superprojeto, segundo o git é:

> Às vezes, desenvolvedores querem obter uma combinação de subdiretórios de um grande projeto, dependendo de qual equipe eles estão. Isso é comum se você está vindo do CVS ou Subversion, onde você define um módulo ou uma coleção de subdiretórios, e você quer manter esse tipo de fluxo de trabalho.
>
> Uma boa maneira de fazer isso no Git é fazer cada subpasta um repositório Git separado e em seguida criar um repositório para um projeto-pai que contêm vários submódulos. A vantagem desse modo é que você pode definir mais especificamente os relacionamentos entre os projetos com tags e branches no projeto-pai.